# data structure to store visited nodes in breadth first search

Tags: data-structures, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

I am applying bfs on a tree where each node have four stacks and one integer in it. I am storing them in a queue. I am using HashSet to store visited nodes. So before adding nodes in queue I am checking if HashSet contains that node or not. But the program is taking too much time to give output. Is my approach right or is there any other method to keep track of visited nodes ? Is Hashset good when we can not represent nodes in array ?
I am providing my code. Following is state class which represents one node.

```
  static class State implements Serializable
  {
     int c=0;  
     Stack s[]=new Stack[4];
     State()
     {        
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
           s[i]=new Stack();
        }
     }
  }
```

My breadth first search algorithm is in following code

```
static int  Bfs(HashSet<state>hs,state st,int n)
{
    hs.add(st);
    LinkedList<state> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    queue.add(st);
    while(!queue.isEmpty())
    {
        state sn=queue.remove();            
        if(sn.s[0].size()==n)
        {                
            return sn.c;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            if(sn.s[i].size()>0)
            {
                int f=i;
                for(int id:IntStream.range(0, 4).filter(x->(x!=f)).toArray())
                {                   

                       state tm=(state)deepcopy(sn); 
                       if((tm.s[id].size()==0)||((int)tm.s[id].peek()>(int)tm.s[i].peek()))
                       {    
                            tm.s[id].push(tm.s[i].pop());
                            if(!hs.contains(tm))
                            {
                                tm.c+=1;
                                hs.add(tm);
                                queue.add(tm);
                            }
                           queue.add(tm);
                       }    
                } 
            }    
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The above code is for problem "https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/gena" which is just like tower of hanoi with 4 stacks. I need to put all disks in first stack. So in each deque operation I am popping last element from one stack and pushing it on other stacks one by one, and I am doing this popping operation on all stacks one by one.So for each state there will be 4x3 neighbours. For loop just stores index of all other stacks in variable id where popped element is to be pushed.

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: The issue here definitely isn't the hash set. Can you explain what all those stacks mean and what your looping conditions are?

Comment: @templatetypedef updated to make it more clear

Comment: @templatetypedef as you can see there is no time consuming method called in bfs in while loop except HashSet.contains() method.

Comment: Even though there aren't many expensive calls here, the search space you're exploring is so huge that the time required just to visit each state might end up by far being the bottleneck.

Comment: No, I have seen other people's submissions their queue size is also growing too much like me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think is a really good way to store visited nodes especially because you cannot store any duplicates in Hashset. This is an alternative. I have coded.

```
    Class Main {
public void bfs()
{
    // BFS uses Queue data structure
    Queue queue = new LinkedList();
    queue.add(this.rootNode);
    printNode(this.rootNode);
    rootNode.visited = true;
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
        Node node = (Node)queue.remove();
        Node child=null;
        while((child=getUnvisitedChildNode(node))!=null) {
            child.visited=true;
            printNode(child);
            queue.add(child);
        }
    }
    // Clear visited property of nodes
    clearNodes();
}
```